# unintended jupyter cell formating

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm new to jupyter and I'm learning to use it to organize my work and to give presentation.  While switch back and forth between the code-mode and the markdown-mode, I think I hit some unintended key combo that changes how the cell looks.  I shutdown and restart the notebook but the changes persists.   I've attached at the end of this post a screenshot -- notice the little box with a faint "1".  What is that little box, what is it called/what does it do, how was it triggled and how do I turn it off?

Many thanks!

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6FpS.png][1]

(edit:  the picture didn't show up so I tried again)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is line number for cells. you can disable it in view-> Toggle Line Numbers.